# Trouble storing JSON Object into JSONB column type in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

I've been stuck on this one for a little while, and I can't seem to find any solution (I've looked around for answers but nothing worked for me in this case)

I have a jsonb column type in my model `Place`:

```
t.jsonb :location
```

I have the maps API returning an object of this type:

```
data = {lat: 52.13661911521592, lng:12.277604312500014}
```

That I turn into a string (otherwise it will only return `[object Object]`:

```
JSON.stringify(data)

{"lat":52.13661911521592,"lng":12.277604312500014}
```

I'm trying to store this object into my jsonb column, but everytime I post, rails return these params:

```
"place"=>{"location"=>"{\"lat\":52.13661911521592,\"lng\":12.277604312500014}"}
```

Which I can't query like I usually do `Place.first.location['lat']`, because it returns `=> 'lat'` and not the value...

I've tried `serialize: :location`, I've tried doing `to_json` on the parameters, the only thing that seems like it *could work somehow* is if I parse the params like so:

```
location = JSON.parse(params['place']['location'])
params['place']['location'] = location
```

But then obviously it returns `blank`...

I've made it work before in the same scenario (same column type, same sort of parameters & object) but I was using rails_admin which did:

```
<%= form.send :hidden_field, field.method_name, value: form.object.location.to_json %>
```

on the stringified object before posting, and I can't seem to figure out why I can't make it work again. (Can I make a `hidden_field` which accesses the object `form.object` without making it too complicated?)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This seems like a very convoluted solution instead of just storing the coordinates in two columns and has huge drawbacks if you're planning on using the coordinates for geospatial queries.

Comment: I had them stored in 2 columns actually, but since I'm only using them for the Maps API, I might as well store them as is (and it's actually easier to integrate with Maps in my case)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had to permit the location parameters as a hash!

In my Places Controller:

```
  params.require(:place).permit(location: {})
```

I'm also using the same logic as rails_admin to send the form:

```
  <%= form.hidden_field :location, value: form.object.location.to_json %>
```